# How do I reapply travertine tile used for a backsplash on my kitchen wall

Tags: kitchens, backsplash

I originally used to double-sided sticky paper to install my travertine tile pieces to the wall, but some have come off and some are loose.  We didn't space them at all just did a pyramid type placement, so no grout is involved.

Answer (score 1):

With travertine you should be using thinset to apply it to the wall.  You don't really need to grout - I have seen it done either way travertine.  If you don't grout then make sure you use a darker grey thinset as it cures into more of a mortar look and also make sure that the thinset isn't squirting up out of your tiles.  So there is a little cleanup to do after applying the thinset.